# Wp7 source of location data

Tags: windows-phone-7

It's possible to get the source of the location data (for example GPS receiver, WI-FI or cellular radio) in windows phone 7 ?

If so, how do I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't available to the developer as it is done at Windows Phone OS level

[GeoCoordinateWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher.aspx)

However specifying the property "DesiredAccuracy" to high will use the GPS receiver - But will use more battery power!
setting it at "Default" will use WiFi or Cell Phone towers to give a much less accurate fix on your location but will be better on battery